# setState is not defined

Tags: reactjs

I have a print function, it first sets the state of `isPrinting` to true and open a pring dialog. Once the dialog is being closed it sets the state of `isPrinting` to `false` and at this point I'm getting the error (second `setState`):

> Uncaught ReferenceError: setState is not defined

I binded function to current context with the arrow function.

```
  handlePrint = () => {
    this.setState({ isPrinting: true }, () => { //setState is working working properly
      window.print();
      if (window.matchMedia) {
        var mediaQueryList = window.matchMedia('print');
        mediaQueryList.addListener = (mql) => {
          if (!mql.matches) {
            this.setState({ isPrinting: false }); //Error
          }
        }
      }
    });
  };
```

Comment: could you provide the whole component please

Comment: did you defined `handlePrint` function inside class?

Comment: @VikashSingh Yes, `export default class SearchResultsPanel extends Component {`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/20279485/1320407 this answer explains why setState is not defined inside the callback of mediaQueryList.addListener. Try prabu-samvel's answer for an apt solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure what you are trying to achieve here but the `window.print()` *freezes* the app. There is no code being run unless someone clicks the printing screen away. I works just like `window.alert("...")`. You can try that by printing a thimestamp right after the `win.print`. So besides that there is a problem with the this context that cannot be reached the whole function is useless. Because you could just do:

```
  handlePrint = () => {
    this.setState({ isPrinting: true }, () => {
      window.print() //freezes until someone clicks it away.
      this.setState({ isPrinting: false }) //Error
    })
  }
```

Regards

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

```
handlePrint = () => {
let _this = this;
this.setState({ isPrinting: true }, () => {
  window.print();
  if (window.matchMedia) {
    var mediaQueryList = window.matchMedia('print');
    mediaQueryList.addListener = (mql) => {
      if (!mql.matches) {
        _this.setState({ isPrinting: false });
      }
    }
  }
});
};
```

Comment: Thank you, I don't get the error anymore but the state doesn't update to `false`.

Answer (score 0):

At the second time, instead of `setState`, just return the new state like:

```
return {
  isPrinting: false,
};
```

Answer (score 0):

This should help

```
  handlePrint = () => {
    this.setState({ isPrinting: true }, () => { //setState is working working properly
      window.print();
      if (window.matchMedia) {
        var mediaQueryList = window.matchMedia('print');
        mediaQueryList.addListener = (mql) => {
          if (!mql.matches) {
            return { isPrinting: false };
          }
        }
      }
    });
  };
```

`setState` method should return a new state rather than try to execute anything.

Answer (score -1):

How did you use the function 'mediaQueryList.addListener'?You can console the two 'this' and see if they are same.